# Using Azure pipeline in yaml to loop through 2 variables simultaneously

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

Requirement: To shutdown or start VM's in a specific resource group using powershell

Variables: List of VM's are stored comma separated in a variable in a variable group which i use split(,) to read each of the during iterating through the loop.
Resource group name also needs to be stored in a variable or can be stored as a parameter as well.

My powershell script:

```
 Param 
    (    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        $AzureVMList,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        $Rgname
    ) 
     
        $AzureVMs = $AzureVMList.Split(",") 
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$AzureVMsToHandle = $AzureVMs 



foreach ( $AzureVM in $AzureVMsToHandle )
{
    Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "$Rgname" -Name  "$AzureVM"
    
}
```

My Azure pipeline outline

```
parameters:
- name: Rgname
  type: object
  default:
  - rg1
  - rg2  
- variables
    vmlist1: vm1,vm2,vm3
    vmlist2: vm4,vm5,vm6

stages: 
  - stage: turnon
    displayName: 'Turn ON VM'
    jobs: 
      - job: 'TurnONVM'
        displayName: 'Turn on VM'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'  
        steps:
        - ${{ each rgname in parameters.resourcegroup }}:
          - task: AzurePowerShell@5
            displayName: turn on myvm"
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
              ScriptType: 'FilePath'
              ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/vm-pipelines/turn-on-vm.ps1'
              ScriptArguments: '-AzureVMList $(vmlist1) -Rgname ${{ parameters.rgname }}'
              azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
              errorActionPreference: silentlyContinue
```

This might work if i have only one resource group. I need to specify multiple resource groups and corresponding variable for storing the list of vm's. I have no idea how would i define pipeline in such a way that execute the script for RG1 with VMlist1 likewise, RG2 with VMlist2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround I can think of to turn on/off multiple VMs in multiple resource groups is using [**matrix**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#strategies) (or [**Multi-job configuration**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-job-configuration)).

For example:

```yaml
stages: 
  - stage: turnon
    displayName: 'Turn ON VM'
    jobs: 
      - job: 'TurnONVM'
        displayName: 'Turn on VM'
        strategy:
          matrix:
            RG1_VM1:
              Rgname: `rg1`
              VM: `vm1`
            RG1_VM2:
              Rgname: `rg1`
              VM: `vm2`
            . . .
        steps:
        - script: |
            echo $(Rgname)
            echo $(VM)
```

With this way,

- you need to enumerate all the pairs of each VM and its corresponding resource group.
- you do not need the loop in the PowerShell script.

Comment: Thanks lot. Figured out late use of matrix. This works too. +1 
I used below script to loop through the VM list. Stored the VM list in a variable and used split to get each one of it.



`Param 
    (    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        $AzureVMList

    ) 
     
        $AzureVMs = $AzureVMList.Split(",") 
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$AzureVMsToHandle = $AzureVMs 


foreach ( $AzureVM in $AzureVMsToHandle )
{



foreach ( $AzureVM2 in $AzureVMsToHandle )
{

Write-Host $RgName "$AzureVM2"
    
}`